# Deploying Ruby on Rails to Heroku failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

https://blog-app-tz.herokuapp.com/ is the link.

Below is the log:

```
2022-04-30T07:28:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user isakawilly10@gmail.com
2022-04-30T07:29:14.481763+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user isakawilly10@gmail.com
2022-04-30T07:29:14.481763+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d73ac101 by user isakawilly10@gmail.com
2022-04-30T07:29:15.013908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-30T07:29:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-04-30T07:29:17.278613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-04-30T07:29:20.581903+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-04-30T07:29:20.581917+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.2.4 application starting in production
2022-04-30T07:29:20.581917+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-04-30T07:29:21.307873+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308147+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/ability.rb:2:in `<class:Ability>': uninitialized constant Ability::CanCan (NameError)
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308149+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/ability.rb:1:in `<main>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308157+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308159+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308160+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `const_get'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308169+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `cget'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308171+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308180+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:26:in `block in ls'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308180+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `each_child'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308182+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `ls'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308190+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:232:in `block in eager_load'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308191+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `synchronize'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308193+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `eager_load'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308200+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `each'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308202+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `eager_load_all'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308203+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:78:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308211+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308214+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308216+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308218+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308219+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308227+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308229+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308230+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308238+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308239+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308241+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308249+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308251+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308253+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308255+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308257+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308265+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308266+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308267+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308275+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308277+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308278+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308286+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308287+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308295+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308296+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308298+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308305+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308307+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308308+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308316+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308317+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308325+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308327+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308337+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308339+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308340+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308348+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.308350+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2022-04-30T07:29:21.426297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-04-30T07:29:21.476815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-04-30T07:29:53.726773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blog-app-tz.herokuapp.com request_id=7a946f44-0183-4f23-a1c2-9fada9f71ac3 fwd="197.186.9.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-30T07:29:54.848484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blog-app-tz.herokuapp.com request_id=1728ec85-d515-40f2-9ebd-91da170abd6d fwd="197.186.9.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-30T07:51:21.840318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blog-app-tz.herokuapp.com request_id=5ccb65eb-5b3c-48f6-805c-165c5e4f39e9 fwd="197.186.6.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-30T07:51:23.057641+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blog-app-tz.herokuapp.com request_id=cba81eae-10af-489c-81f0-17511d4ae0fd fwd="197.186.6.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information than that.

Comment: Your app is starting. I don't think there is a problem at Heroku. Just you are using `Ability::CanCan` which is a module not recognized by your app. It seems to be coming from gem CanCan (that is 10 years old and been replaced by CanCanCan). I don't use this gem though I can find module `include CanCan::Ability` Are you sure there isn't any typo in your code so that you have mixed up the module name from CanCan gem ?

Comment: Seems CanCanCan uses a similar module (sorry I inferred you were using CanCan)

Comment: @PeterMortensen like which information?

Comment: `% ruby -rcancancan -e 'p CanCan' => CanCan` Is your application loading the gem? Is your test suite passing?

Comment: What does your `/app/app/models/ability.rb` file look like and what version of the `cancan` gem do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/isaka-lumato/budget-app-2.0 is the link to the repo

Comment: @IsaacWilliamLumato the Gemfile does not seem to include the `cancancan` gem. Do you know how to fix this?